# ng-bind-html accessing the DOM angular jquery

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am reframing my question here.

This is my html code where I load the content from the DB using ng-bind-html

```
<html>
<body>
<section  ng-bind-html='article.description' tagparagragh>
</section>  
</body>
</html>
```

Using Angular.js ,I wrote a directive to access the DOM that gets loaded in the description.In the linkFn function, I can't add the css class to a span  inside the description html which I got from the DB.Can someone help me..thanks

```
app.directive('tagparagraph', function () { 
function linkFn(scope,element,attrs){               
    angular.element('section').find("p").addClass("paraClass");     
  };      
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    link: linkFn,
    transclude:true,    
  };
```

});

Comment: Have you tried with any code that you are hoping to achieve? If so can you share that code so that we have a better look into it?

Comment: I am trying to do it locally before pushing it to other domains.But I am kind of clueless where to start with

Comment: appending an icon to the end is not a big task unless and until have a look on how you are rendering each paragraph in the view.

Comment: I am using ng-bind-html to render the html from Database.Is there a way I can manipulate the DOM after the content is rendered.

Comment: without seeing HTML content. It's hard to predict that.